# Repeating the "go" cycle from scratch every 1000 ticks

Tags: time, netlogo

I am working on a simplified model of the stock market, and I am still learning to manage time in NetLogo. In my model a day is made of 1000 ticks. In a day several things happen: turtles sell and buy stocks, at some point during the day they set their strategies, various logs are written and then erased at the end of the day.

I would like the model to start again after 1000 ticks, i.e. at the end of the day the model does not stop but starts again, thus simulating more than one single day.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `if ticks mod 1000 = 0 [setup-locations]`

Comment: Because the setup procedure simply defines the different breeds and the world (and resets ticks!). The decision-making part of the code is within the go procedure, I don't need ticks to be reset or the world to be cleared, I just need the same turtles to start again their operations from the beginning every 1000 ticks.

Comment: So, why don't you abstract your code from the setup function that defines where the locations are and call that instead of setup? I've modified my answer.

Comment: Sorry mattsap, I have spent some time trying to figure out what you mean but I could not (I am sorry, I am completely new to netlogo). Could you try to clarify?

Comment: You said you didn't want the model to completely restart, but instead the agents should go back to their original starting locations. Somewhere in your setup, you had to specify the agents original starting locations. Take the code that is related to the agents starting locations and put that into a function. Call that function like above.

Comment: Matt is right. You should not reset the tick counter to 0 in this situation. Let it keep incrementing. Simulation time is only moving forward here, not backward, so the tick counter should not move backward either.